# Как рисовать с помощью ESC последовательностей меню в терминале?

Tags: c

Думаю как проще это сделать на си. Мне нужно нарисовать меню для терминала с ESC последовательностями. Не знаю как лучше это сделать на си нужен как-то более менее простой способ. Чтобы можно было быстро заполнять экран информацией. Делать ввод данных с клавиатуры.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону ncurses может быть.

Answer (score -2):

Ну, переводите консоль в юникод. В линуксе она, как правило, уже сразу в юникоде.

Под вендой поможет chcp.

Потом открываете [википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) [image: введите сюда описание изображения] и рисуете в свое удовольствие.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
 int main(); 
 {
     printf("\u2591\u2591\2591\n"); 
     return 0;
 }
```